# how can i get cacheKey when use spring cache?

Tags: spring, spring-cache

how can i get cacheKey when use spring cache? For example, the following code , How should this function( getCacheKey()) be implemented?

```
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut)")
public Object processCachePut(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
    Method realMethod = getRealMethod(point);
    Object result = point.proceed();
        String notice = null;
        if (realMethod.isAnnotationPresent(CachePut.class)) {
            CachePut cachePut = realMethod.getDeclaredAnnotation(CachePut.class);

            String key = getCacheKey();
        }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String key = cachePut.key()`  when you got a annotation from method , it's a instance contains annotation's property

Comment: thank you,but when code is written like this, it does not work.
    @CachePut(value = "TEST",key="'ba'+#key")
    public Date now(String key) {
        return new Date();
    }

Comment: the cache key use SpEL

Comment: @andy I know key is template string not a instance value ,right?  maybe you can use springEL to parsing the key-string.

Comment: thank you,key is not an instance variable.The prerequisite for building SpEL is difficult.                                                                                     
    EvaluationContext evaluationContext = createEvaluationContext(result);
    return evaluator.key(this.metadata.operation.getKey(),this.methodCacheKey, evaluationContext);

Comment: If you just code for specific method , you can just get method temp variables by `pjp.getArgs()` but that's hard code 。

Comment: thank you,I want to achieve universal functions. Hard coding is wrong in many scenarios.